# Characteristic Function of Mirrored Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, integration, fourier-analysis

Im currently working on option pricing using characteristic funcitons, anf have come across a problem.

**BACKGROUND:**

I have implemented an algorithm that generates the characteristic function giving the pdf in blue:
[image]

These oscillations prove very difficult to remove due to the cutoff. Because of the nature of the options I am pricing, what the pdf does left of the cutoff does not matter.

Hence, I had the idea of mirroring the right hand side of the pdf to the left side, creating somewhat of a  bell curve in this situation. This would take away the cutoff and thus allow me to use spectral filters (used to remove this oscillating 'noise') more effectively.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have a characteristic function for some unknown $f(y)$, the definition of a characteristic funtion is
$$
\phi(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iuy} f(y)dy
$$

Can I transform this into the characteristic function for a function $g(y)$ which is defined as:

$$
g(y) = \begin{cases}
f(-(y+a))&\text{ if }y<a, \hspace{1cm}\\ 
f(y)&\text{ if }y\geq a\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $a$ is the axis i want to mirror from.

Answer (score 1):

You're defenition of g can't be a density function.

Lets say $X\sim U(0,1)$ so $f_X=1_{(0,1)}$  And if we choose $a=0$.
We'll try to define Y with a density function $g(t)=1_{(-1,1)}$

But now $\lim _{t\rightarrow \infty}F_Y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t g(t)dt=2$, so g cannot be a density function.

Comment: *”Because of the nature of the options I am pricing, what the pdf does left of the cutoff does not matter.”* I know, but in my use case, this is not an issue.